# Fastest way to read a data.frame into a shiny app on load?

Tags: r, shiny, read.csv

For a shiny app in a repository containing a single static data file, what is the optimal format for that flat file (and corresponding function to read that file) which minimises the read time for that flat file to a data.frame?

For example, suppose when a shiny app starts it reads an `.RDS`, but suppose that takes ~30 seconds and we wish to decrease that. Are there any methods of saving the file and using a function which can save time?

Here's what I know already:

- I have been reading some speed comparison articles, but none seem to comprehensive benchmark all methods in the context of a shiny app (and possible cores/threading implications). Some offer sound advice like [trying to load in less data](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-speed-up-loading-data-at-start-of-shiny-app/59923)
- I notice languages like julia can sometimes be faster, but I'm not sure if reading a file using another language would help since it would have to be converted to an object R recognises, and presumably that process would take longer than simply reading as an R object initially
- I have noticed identical files seem to be smaller when saved as `.RDS` compared to `.csv`, however, I'm not sure if file size necessarily has an effect on read time.

Comment: Usually, `.rds` is pretty much the fastest for loading all data, without "lazy" loading partial columns. If you know you don't need all columns, all rows *immediately*, then `feather` formats allege some good performance. `vroom` package claims some improvements for delimited files, same premise.

Comment: @r2evans interesting. I'll check out feather and vroom. I was curious about RDS. RDS files seem a lot smaller than their equivalent csv, so I reasoned perhaps they were compressed, and if that's correct, that they may take time to decompress. That's just postulation though

Comment: From [`?saveRDS`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/readRDS.html): *"compress: a logical specifying whether saving to a named file is to use `"gzip"` compression, or one of `"gzip"`, `"bzip2"` or `"xz"` to indicate the type of compression to be used. Ignored if `file` is a connection."*

Comment: @r2evans thanks, good find. So something like `saveRDS(iris, "iris.RDS")` would use compression. I don't know enough about the topic, but would presume de/compressing would take longer than not doing so

Comment: Certainly, so removing compression can help with some speed, but the RDS format is binary-efficient and R does a really good job. It is generally fine for most, but you'll need to do some benchmarks for your data to determine if uncompressed will give you any speed improvements.

Comment: Likely relevant: https://data.nozav.org/post/2019-r-data-frame-benchmark/ and https://blog.dominodatalab.com/the-r-data-i-o-shootout/. If you're amenable to database-like files, consider SQLite or a newcomer `duckdb` that claims speed improvements.

Comment: @r2evans very nice. I'll read those articles. I think SQLite requires an actual database? And therefore storing the data.frame as a table? If that's what you mean, I'll check that out (and duckdb too)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222874/discussion-between-r2evans-and-stevec).

Comment: I had a similar problem with a shiny app. I mainly needed to read and save data frames and lists as the user uses the app. The solution that worked to me is:
1. .rds without any compression
2. Store each file separatedly in the most primitive way as possible. 

To elaborate on the latter. I use several data frames within a R6Class. I first tried saving the whole R6 instance but it consumed a lot of space. Then I just saved every data frame as a separated .rds and it worked much faster. I needed them separated bc they are updated and saved within the app.

Comment: @TomasCapretto very interesting, never thought about R6 class, will look into it

Comment: @stevec I don't know if there is a proper way to share code here in SO. If you are interested I could share that part of my app (or my app if you want) so you have a look at it.